# What if base.OnCreateView(.....) is not called when overridden?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Here is the code that inherits from fragment.

I tried it without `base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` and it worked just fine. Is it necessary to call it?

It looks like it calls the Abstract Class and supposedly registers View but do we have to do it ?

OnCreateView is overridden and here it is

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View oView = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.EntityDetailsDialogFragment, container, false);

        return oView;
    }
```

Comment: Is that Android? Then you mean `onCreateView`. And `override` is not a valid method modifier in Java.

Comment: I apologize - this is Xamarin (C#) - super.OnCreateView() I believe

Comment: Then please use the relevant tags :)

Comment: Please accept my apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is open-source, so you can check for yourself.  This is the source of `Fragment.onCreateView()`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup , @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return null;
}
```

Calling `super.onCreateView()` won't do anything since there's no implementation.  Also, this method returns a value unlike other lifecycle methods like `onCreate()`, so to do something meaningful you would have to do `View blah = super.onCreateView()` since you are otherwise throwing away the return value.